# Iis it possible to encrypt Lambda environment variables with the default KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

In the AWS Console under "Encryption configuration", I noticed I can't encrypt my environment variables using the default Lambda KMS.

Am I missing something? Or do I have to create my own key to enable encryption at rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use your own key to use the KMS helpers if you want to encrypt things after the function is created. Here are the [relevant docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html#env_encrypt):

> The first time you create or update Lambda functions that use
>   environment variables in a region, a default service key is created
>   for you automatically within AWS KMS. This key is used to encrypt
>   environment variables. However, should you wish to use encryption
>   helpers and use KMS to encrypt environment variables after your Lambda
>   function is created, then you must create your own AWS KMS key and
>   choose it instead of the default key. The default key will give errors
>   when chosen.